# The client has no active subscriptions over endpoint 'my-polling-amf'

Tags: apache-flex, jms, blazeds, consumer

This is my channel configuration:

```
channel-definition id="my-polling-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel"endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amfpolling" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/propertiesserializationlegacy-collectiontrue/legacy-collectionlegacy-maptrue/legacy-map/serializationpolling-enabledtrue/polling-enabledpolling-interval-seconds4/polling-interval-seconds /properties/channel-definition
```

I have the following scenario, two users logging to application from same machine using same browser but different instances; if one of the users logs out which eventually disconncts the channel, the second user will get this message "The client has no active subscriptions over endpoint 'my-polling-amf'" message in fault handler then disconnect and reconnect. However if both users were using different kind of browsers, for instance user1 using firefox and user2 using IE it will work fine, nothing odd shows up.Thank you.

*the exception is:*

```
flex.messaging.client.FlexClientNotSubscribedException: The client has no active subscriptions over endpoint 'my-polling-amf'.
    at flex.messaging.client.FlexClient.throwNotSubscribedException(FlexClient.java:1789)
    at flex.messaging.client.FlexClient.pollWithWait(FlexClient.java:967)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.BasePollingHTTPEndpoint.handleFlexClientPoll(BasePollingHTTPEndpoint.java:538)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.handleFlexClientPollCommand(AbstractEndpoint.java:1151)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.serviceMessage(AbstractEndpoint.java:965)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1a3ef066.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:692)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.flex.core.MessageInterceptionAdvice.invoke(MessageInterceptionAdvice.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$FixedChainStaticTargetInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:576)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$67891845.serviceMessage(<generated>)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.MessageBrokerFilter.invoke(MessageBrokerFilter.java:103)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.LegacyFilter.invoke(LegacyFilter.java:158)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SessionFilter.invoke(SessionFilter.java:44)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.BatchProcessFilter.invoke(BatchProcessFilter.java:67)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(SerializationFilter.java:166)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseHTTPEndpoint.java:291)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$67891845.service(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.handle(MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:272)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1730)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: What is that 'same browser with different instances'? Did you try other browsers 'with different instances'? What do you treat as 'instance' -  do you create different processes for that, or just different tabs or windows? However, it seems that you have to provide more information for user identification to force server think that there are two users, not one.

Comment: i have used Chrome to test with different instances, created different processes.Once i disconnect one of the instance,the other is influenced

Comment: i print the error log:Detected duplicate HTTP-based FlexSessions, generally due to the remote host disabling session cookies. Session cookies must be enabled to manage the client connection correctly.    so how can i config the BlazeDS server and make it support two server in one PC? and body can help me ?